# Error encountered while installing windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

today I formatted my laptop because it was starting to give problems. For the installation of windows I used a USB stick, during the installation however it said that it was impossible to install the windows files and the error was 0x8007023D. From what I read the error may have been due to the stick but I'm not sure. Some advice? Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that a file is missing (or damaged).

- is your copy of windows official ?
- have you tested with another USB stick ?

Comment: yes the copy of windows is official (I downloaded it from the microsoft website through their tool)
but I have not yet tried to use another usb stick.
so this error is due to the lack of files or their corruption?
because I read that it could also be due to the ram. Ty for the help